# What is the respective arrangement of Lord Vishnu's weapons in 24 Salagramas?

Tags: vishnu, weapon

There are 24 types of Salagramams available for Lord Vishnu. Shank, Chakra, Gadha and Lotus ---- in which order it should come for these 24 types of salagramams and in which purana it is mentioned?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shaligrama Stones are used for iconic representation of Lord Vishnu. Shaligrama Stones are Swayambhu (they don't need [Prana Prathista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prana_Pratishtha)) just like how Banalingas are Swayambhu stones of Lord Shiva.

These Shaligrama stones have marks of four weapons (Shankha, Chakra, Gada and Padma) of Lord Vishnu. As there are 4 weapons, 4! arrangements are possible and each arrangments has a specific name of Lord Vishnu. The 24 arrangements and respective name is described in [Chapter 45 of Garuda Purana.](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/20541/4/Chapter%202_81-160p.pdf) (Pg No- 142)

> These [arrangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaligram#Configurations) and respective name of Lord Vishnu are:
>
> 1. Shanka, chakra, gada and padma - Keshava
> 2. Padma, gada, chakra, shanka - Narayana
> 3. Chakra, shanka, padma and gada - Madhava
> 4. Gada, padma, shanka and chakra - Govinda
> 5. Padma, shanka, chakra and gada – Vishnu
> 6. Shanka, padma, gada, chakra – Madusudhana
> 7. Gada, chakra, shanka and padma – Trivikrama
> 8. Chakra, gada, padma, shanka - Vamana
> 9. Chakra, padma, shanka, gada - Shridhara
> 10. Padma, gada, shanka, charka - Hrishikesh
> 11. Padma, chakra,gada, shanka - Padmanabha
> 12. Shanka, chakra, gada, padma - Damodara
> 13. Chakra, shanka, gada, padma - Sankarshana
> 14. Shanka, chakra, padma, gada - Pradyumna
> 15. Gada, shanka, padma, charka - Aniruddha
> 16. Padma, shanka, gada, chakra - Purushottama
> 17. Gadha, shanka, chakra, padma - Adokshaja
> 18. Padma, gada, shanka, chakra - Narasimha
> 19. Padma, chakra, shanka, gada – Achyuta
> 20. Shanka, chakra, padma, gada - Janardana
> 21. Gada, padma, shanka, chakra - Upendra
> 22. Chakra, padma, gada and shanka – Hari
> 23. Gada, padma, chakra and shanka - Krishna
> 24. Shanka, chakra, padma, gada – Vasudeva

Comment: Nice copy and pasting--- even everybody will do that-- difficult to byheart in order.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan Order is same as Garuda Purana. Why to type when it is available on Wiki exactly as mentioned in Garuda Purana?

Comment: @des--That is what I have told nice copy and paste--Source wiki or GP all are one at the same.

Comment: Can women and shudras worship Shaligrama

Comment: Factorial 4 = 4! = 4X3X2X1=24 types.