# Vishnu and His mercy in His hands

Tags: vishnu, krishna, weapon

This is Keshava Vishnu.

Keshava means His hair is curly and black.

I have heard many times that Krishna (or Vishnu) is very merciful, however, as He holds different objects on His hands - Mace, Discus, lotus flower and Conch-shell, so His mercy can be given in different ways.

Generally the lotus flower and the conshell are for devotees, so to say - an example of lines I have heard.

the question is:

**where in the scriptures is this described?**

in anyways, Keshava Vishnu, (or Krishna) is always beyond the reach of our material senses, and we can never understand the full picture.

[image]

Comment: Can you more clear?! Can't get it what you want to ask ? Please ask your question in clear way so everybody can understand it Thanks :)

Comment: where in the scriptures is this described? I would like to know where exactly in the scriptures this is described. apologies if I was not clear

Comment: See this question [Salagramams of Lord Vishnu](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14956/3500)

Comment: @TheDestroyer thanks - that was very good of you sharing it here.

Comment: @marcellomiorelli Thanks but that is on Shaligrama stones but I don't know scriptures that describe real Lord Vishnu in Keshava form.